# Python 3 error print brackets no use

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

```
print_n(s, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    print(s)
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Please Help!

Comment: Is that supposed to be a method

Comment: What line do you get the syntax error

Comment: Use `def print_n(s, n):` instead? The syntax of function definition is right here https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your indentation (Python IS sensitive to indentation) and add a `def` before your function. I would advise you to look into a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) that gives a brief overview of Python.

```
def print_n(s, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    print(s)
```

Comment: I'd like to highlight that the question was posted with indentation, but that the indentation was with mostly (but not entirely) with tabs instead of spaces. This meant that the formatting got a little mashed, with most of the code going up against the edge. It's probably worth mentioning that tabs are a bad idea too `:)`

Comment: Oh... *awkward silence* :D